# itemSize not animating with setCollectionViewLayout(toLayout, animated: true);

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Hello I'm trying to work with UICollection views and have them have multiple layouts.

When I use swift/obj-cs setCollectionViewLayout(toLayout, animated: true); the animation does rearrange the cells but the item in the cells jump to the final size instead of growing gradually along with the cell and the end result is a bad looking animations.

Here are my two layouts I'm switching between:

```
{
    override init()
    {
        super.init()
        minimumLineSpacing = 20.0;
        minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0;
        itemSize = CGSizeMake(80.0, 80.0)
        sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0, 60.0, 20.0, 60.0)
    }


    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
    }
```

And the other:

```
{
    override init()
    {
        super.init()
        minimumLineSpacing = 10.0;
        minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0;
        itemSize = CGSizeMake(150.0, 150.0)
        sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0)
    }


    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
    }
```

And the code used to change the layouts:

```
func changeLayoutWithLayout(toLayout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout)
{
    self.setCollectionViewLayout(toLayout, animated: true);

}
```

Is there anyway to get the itemSize animating properly?  or to create my own custom animation for the transition?  I tried to do the batchupdates method but that gives me the same result where the itemsize jumps to its final value.

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure this out? I'm getting exactly the same problem

Comment: @MichaelForrest sadly I never found a solution to the problem.  I tried a couple of manual animation methods but everything I tried either had bad performance or looked wrong.  I actually just abandoned UIKit all together and do 90% of my work in SpriteKit now.

Answer (score 1):

I find that `UIColletionViewCell` and `UIColletionViewCell.contentView` have different behavior during animation invoked by  `setCollectionViewLayout(toLayout, animated: true)`, the cell's size grows gradually while the `contentView` jumps to the final size. 
But apple suggests the content view is the main view to which you should add you cell's custom content.

Answer (score 0):

when you call the func changeLayoutWithLayout,you may try to initialize the  layou again.